# Node graph implementation for a material system

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I'm working on a material/shader graph system. I came up with a simple solution, but nodes that weren't connected were used in some situations. So, I thought of using Kahn's algorithm to execute nodes' tasks. I'm not quite sure if it's a proper implementation.

I've only played with it, so it's a single file to avoid jumping between many files.

https://godbolt.org/z/8hYEWbGsv

includes

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <memory_resource>
```

There is a generic `DAG` class that references `Node`s and `Edge`s.
It also sorts and executes nodes' code - `DAG::Execute()` function

```cpp
struct DAG 
{
    DAG()
    {
        nodes.reserve(16);
        edges.reserve(32);
    }
    ~DAG() = default;
    DAG(const DAG&) = delete;
    DAG& operator=(const DAG&) = delete;

    struct Node 
    {
        Node(DAG& dag)
            : id(dag.AddNode(this))
        {
        }
        virtual ~Node() = default;

        Node(const Node&) = delete;
        Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;

        virtual void Execute() = 0;

        [[nodiscard]] inline std::size_t getID() const { return id; }
        [[nodiscard]] inline std::uint32_t getRefCount() const { return refCount; }

        inline void MakeTarget() { target = true; }
        [[nodiscard]] inline bool isTarget() const { return target; }

    private:
        friend struct DAG;

        std::uint32_t refCount = 0;
        const std::size_t id = 0;
        bool target = false;
    };

    struct Edge
    {
        Edge(DAG& dag, const std::size_t fromNode, const std::size_t toNode)
            : fromNode(fromNode), toNode(toNode)
        {
            dag.AddEdge(this);
        }

        Edge(const Edge&) = delete;
        Edge& operator=(const Edge& rhs) = delete;

        const std::size_t fromNode = 0;
        const std::size_t toNode = 0;
    };

    [[nodiscard]] inline auto getOutgoingEdges(const Node* const node)
    {
        return edges | std::views::filter([node](const Edge* const edge) { return edge->fromNode == node->getID(); });
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline auto getIncomingEdges(const Node* const node)
    {
        return edges | std::views::filter([node](const Edge* const edge) { return edge->toNode == node->getID(); });
    }

    void Execute();

private:
    [[nodiscard]] inline std::size_t AddNode(Node* node)
    {
        std::size_t id = nodes.size();
        nodes.push_back(node);
        return id;
    }

    inline void AddEdge(Edge* edge)
    {
        edges.push_back(edge);
    }

    std::vector<Node*> nodes;
    std::vector<Edge*> edges;
};

void DAG::Execute()
{
    //Reset nodes refCount before sorting
    for (Node* const node : nodes) {
        node->refCount = 0;
    }

    for (const Edge* const edge : edges) {
        Node* const node = nodes[edge->fromNode];
        node->refCount++;
    }

    std::vector<Node*> stack;
    for (Node* const node : nodes) {
        if (node->getRefCount() == 0) {
            stack.push_back(node);
        }
    }

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        Node* const node = stack.back();
        stack.pop_back();

        //If the current node is not a target
        //and if it hasn't got out edges
        //don't execute the Node::Execute() function
        //and don't process it's incoming edges
        auto&& outEdges = getOutgoingEdges(node);
        if (outEdges.empty() && !node->isTarget()) {
            continue;
        }

        node->Execute();

        auto&& edges = getIncomingEdges(node);
        for (const Edge* const edge : edges) {
            Node* const linkedNode = nodes[edge->fromNode];
            if (--linkedNode->refCount == 0) {
                stack.push_back(linkedNode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm not sure in `DAG::Execute()` function is this part:

```cpp
auto&& outEdges = getOutgoingEdges(node);
if (outEdges.empty() && !node->isTarget()) {
    continue;
}
```

I don't even know why, but it just feels not right. It's not a standard Kahn algorithm, but I need it to cull not connected nodes. See the results at the end of this question.

The final `Node`, `Edge` and `Pin` look like this:

```cpp
struct Graph;

struct Node : DAG::Node
{
    Node(Graph& g, const std::string_view name);

    void Execute() override;

    inline void AddInput(const std::size_t pinID) { inputs.push_back(pinID); }
    inline void AddOuput(const std::size_t outputID) { outputs.push_back(outputID); }

    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::string& getName() const { return name; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::vector<size_t>& getInputs() const { return inputs; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::vector<size_t>& getOutputs() const { return outputs; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline bool hasInputs() const { return !inputs.empty(); }
    [[nodiscard]] inline bool hasOutputs() const { return !outputs.empty(); }

private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> inputs;
    std::vector<std::size_t> outputs;

    Graph& g;
    const std::string name;
};

struct Pin
{
    Pin(const std::string_view name, const std::size_t id, const std::size_t nodeID)
        : name(name), id(id), nodeID(nodeID)
    {
    }

    [[nodiscard]] inline std::size_t getID() const { return id; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline std::size_t getNodeID() const { return nodeID; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline std::uint32_t getRefCount() const { return refCount; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline bool isCulled() const { return refCount == 0; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::string& getName() const { return name; }

    inline void IncrementRefCount() { refCount++; }
    inline void Reset() { refCount = 0; }

    inline void AddOutputEdge(const std::size_t id) { outputEdges.push_back(id); }
    inline void setInputEdge(const std::size_t id) { inputEdge = id; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::vector<std::size_t>& getOutputEdges() const { return outputEdges; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::optional<std::size_t>& getInputEdge() const { return inputEdge; }

private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> outputEdges;
    std::optional<std::size_t> inputEdge = std::nullopt;

    std::string name;

    std::uint32_t refCount = 0;
    const std::size_t id = 0;
    const std::size_t nodeID = 0;
};

struct Edge : DAG::Edge
{
    Edge(Graph& g, 
        const std::size_t fromPin, 
        const std::size_t toPin, 
        const std::size_t fromNode, 
        const std::size_t toNode);

    const std::size_t fromPin = 0;
    const std::size_t toPin = 0;
};
```

Note that `Pin` is not a part of `DAG`.
I wanted to implement some abstraction like

`struct PinNode : DAG::Node` - holds connections

`struct VirtualPin` - actual pin type, has a reference/id to `PinNode`

but after a while it didn't seem like a good idea

Also, I'm not sure how I should return `std::optional<std::size_t> inputEdge` in `getInputEdge()` function. `const &` is ok or should I just return a copy?

`Node` and `Edge` constructors will be defined after `Graph` implementation

Here it is:

```cpp
struct Graph
{
    Graph(std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource& linearArena)
        : linearArena(linearArena)
    {
        nodes.reserve(16);
        edges.reserve(32);
        pins.reserve(64);
    }
    Graph(const Graph&) = delete;
    Graph& operator=(const Graph&) = delete;
    ~Graph() = default;

    [[nodiscard]] Node* AddNode(const std::string_view name);

    [[nodiscard]] Pin* AddInput(const std::string_view name, Node* const owner);
    [[nodiscard]] Pin* AddOutput(const std::string_view name, Node* const owner);

    bool Connect(Pin* const from, Pin* const to);

    void Execute();

    [[nodiscard]] inline const Node* getNode(const std::size_t id) const { return nodes[id]; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const Pin* getPin(const std::size_t id) const { return pins[id]; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline const DAG& getDag() const { return dag; }
    [[nodiscard]] inline DAG& getDag() { return dag; }

    [[nodiscard]] inline const std::pmr::vector<Pin*>& getPins() const { return pins; }
private:
    [[nodiscard]] Pin* AddPin(const std::string_view name, Node* const owner);

    template<typename T, size_t alignment = alignof(T), typename ... Args>
    [[nodiscard]] T* ArenaAllocate(Args&& ... args)
    {
        void* const p = linearArena.allocate(sizeof(T), alignment);
        return p ? new(p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) : nullptr;
    }

    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource& linearArena;

    DAG dag;
    std::pmr::vector<Node*> nodes{&linearArena};
    std::pmr::vector<Edge*> edges{&linearArena};
    std::pmr::vector<Pin*> pins{&linearArena};
};

Node* Graph::AddNode(const std::string_view name) 
{
    auto node = ArenaAllocate<Node>(*this, name);
    nodes.push_back(node); 
    return node;
}

Pin* Graph::AddInput(const std::string_view name, Node* const owner)
{
    auto pin = AddPin(name, owner);
    owner->AddInput(pin->getID());
    return pin;
}

Pin* Graph::AddOutput(const std::string_view name, Node* const owner)
{
    auto pin = AddPin(name, owner);
    owner->AddOuput(pin->getID());
    return pin;
}

Pin* Graph::AddPin(const std::string_view name, Node* const owner)
{
    std::size_t id = pins.size();
    auto pin = ArenaAllocate<Pin>(name, id, owner->getID());
    pins.push_back(pin);
    return pin;
}

bool Graph::Connect(Pin* const from, Pin* const to)
{
    if (to->getInputEdge().has_value()) {
        return false;
    }

    const std::size_t id = edges.size();

    auto edge = ArenaAllocate<Edge>(
        *this, 
        from->getID(), 
        to->getID(), 
        from->getNodeID(), 
        to->getNodeID()
    );
    edges.push_back(edge);
    from->AddOutputEdge(id);
    to->setInputEdge(id);

    return true;
}

void Graph::Execute()
{
    //Reset pins refCount before each DAG::Execute() call
    for(auto pin : pins) {
        pin->Reset();
    }
    //Calculate pins refCount
    for (const Edge* const edge : edges) {
        Pin& pin = *pins[edge->fromPin];
        pin.IncrementRefCount();
    }
    dag.Execute();
}

Node::Node(Graph& g, const std::string_view name)
    : DAG::Node(g.getDag()), g(g), name(name)
{
}

Edge::Edge(Graph& g, 
    const std::size_t fromPin, 
    const std::size_t toPin, 
    const std::size_t fromNode, 
    const std::size_t toNode)
        : DAG::Edge(g.getDag(), fromNode, toNode), fromPin(fromPin), toPin(toPin)
{
}
```

right now `Node::Execute()` simply prints inputs and outputs

```cpp
void Node::Execute()
{
    std::cout << "\nNode: " << name << "\n";
    std::cout << "  Inputs:\n";
    
    if(inputs.empty()) {
        std::cout << "   empty   \n";
    } else {
        for (auto inputID : inputs) {
            auto input = g.getPin(inputID);
            std::cout << "   " << input->getName() << "\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "  Outputs:\n";
    auto unculledOutputs = getOutputs() | std::views::filter([&pins = g.getPins()](auto pinID) { return !pins[pinID]->isCulled(); });
    for (auto outputID : unculledOutputs) {
        auto output = g.getPin(outputID);
        std::cout << "   " << output->getName() << "\n";
    }
}
```

but in a future it'll convert outputs into some variables. I haven't fully written it yet.

main function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource arena{1024 * 1024};
    Graph sg{arena};

    auto lit = sg.AddNode("Lit");
    [[maybe_unused]] auto basePin = sg.AddInput("material.baseColor", lit);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto normalPin = sg.AddInput("material.normal", lit);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto materialAlphaPin = sg.AddInput("material.alpha", lit);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto metallicPin = sg.AddInput("material.metallic", lit);
    [[maybe_unused]] auto roughnessPin = sg.AddInput("material.roughness", lit);
    lit->MakeTarget();

    auto alphaNode = sg.AddNode("Alpha");
    auto alphaPin = sg.AddOutput("alpha", alphaNode);

    auto multiplierNode = sg.AddNode("Multiplier");
    auto multiplierPin = sg.AddOutput("multiplier", multiplierNode);

    auto addNode = sg.AddNode("AddNode");
    auto a = sg.AddInput("a", addNode);
    auto b = sg.AddInput("b", addNode);
    auto out = sg.AddOutput("out", addNode);

    sg.Connect(alphaPin, a);
    sg.Connect(multiplierPin, b);
    sg.Connect(out, materialAlphaPin);

    sg.Execute();

    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program:

```
Node: Lit
  Inputs:
   material.baseColor
   material.normal
   material.alpha
   material.metallic
   material.roughness
  Outputs:

Node: AddNode
  Inputs:
   a
   b
  Outputs:
   out

Node: Multiplier
  Inputs:
   empty   
  Outputs:
   multiplier

Node: Alpha
  Inputs:
   empty   
  Outputs:
   alpha
```

It looks good. Now let's disconnect `alphaPin` from `a` pin, just comment out this line in the main function: `sg.Connect(alphaPin, a);` and run again:

```
Node: Lit
  Inputs:
   material.baseColor
   material.normal
   material.alpha
   material.metallic
   material.roughness
  Outputs:

Node: AddNode
  Inputs:
   a
   b
  Outputs:
   out

Node: Multiplier
  Inputs:
   empty   
  Outputs:
   multiplier
```

Also looks good. `Alpha` Node hasn't been printed since its pin is not connected.

If `DAG::Execute` wouldn't have:

```cpp
auto&& outEdges = getOutgoingEdges(node);
if (outEdges.empty() && !node->isTarget()) {
    continue;
}
```

the it would look like this:

```
Node: Alpha
  Inputs:
   empty   
  Outputs:

Node: Lit
  Inputs:
   material.baseColor
   material.normal
   material.alpha
   material.metallic
   material.roughness
  Outputs:

Node: AddNode
  Inputs:
   a
   b
  Outputs:
   out

Node: Multiplier
  Inputs:
   empty   
  Outputs:
   multiplier
```

which is not correct, because `Alpha` node is processed.

Could you do a review of this code and say if this code in `DAG::Execute()`:

```cpp
auto&& outEdges = getOutgoingEdges(node);
if (outEdges.empty() && !node->isTarget()) {
    continue;
}
```

is corrected and I'm just freaking out?

Comment: If the output is wrong, it's not ready for Code Review.

Comment: I haven't meant that the output is wrong. I've asked for a general code review + modification I did with Kahn's algorithm and `if(outEdges.empty() ...` thing

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make better use of polymorphic allocators

The whole point of polymorphic allocators is so that containers that use those can transparently use that allocator to allocate memory for the objects they store. Of course, if you want stable pointers to elements stored in a container, you cannot use `std::vector`, however you can use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) or [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead. So instead of doing:

```
std::pmr::vector<Node*> nodes{&linearArena};
…
auto node = ArenaAllocate<Node>(*this, name);
nodes.push_back(node);
return node;
```

You want to do this:

```
std::pmr::deque<Node> nodes{&linearArena};
…
return &nodes.emplace_back(name);
```

Once you store everything by value, copying graphs also becomes safe, and you no longer need to delete the copy constructors.

## Prefer passing references where appropriate

You pass pointers everywhere, but especially if you store items in PMR containers by value, then it makes sense to pass references instead, so for example:

```
Pin& Graph::AddPin(std::string_view name, Node& owner)
{
    std::size_t id = pins.size();
    return pins.emplace_back(name, id, owner.getID());
}
```

References must always be non-null, so the compiler and/or static analyzers could spot bugs more easily, they also cannot be changed to point to another object, so `const` is not necessary anymore.

Note that whereever you used `auto` variables to hold a pointer, now you should use `auto&` to hold a reference, otherwise a copy will be made.

## Avoid double bookkeeping

There seems to be some double bookkeeping going on. `Graph` owns the nodes, edges and pins, but then in also has a `DAG` that stores pointers to exactly the same nodes and edges. This is all done seemingly to make `Execute()` a bit simpler to implement.

I see two ways around this. One is to make `DAG` a base class of `Graph`, and add virtual functions to `DAG` that allow `Execute` access to the nodes and edges without having to store pointers to them itself.

Another way is to do away with `DAG` entirely, and instead make a templated free function that can work on any kind of graph. For example:

```
template<typename Nodes, typename Edges, typename Executor>
void execute_dag(Nodes& nodes, Edges& edges, Executor&& executor)
{
    for (auto& node: nodes) {
         node.refCount = 0;
    }
    …
    std::stack<Nodes::pointer> stack;
    for (auto& node: nodes) {
        if (node.getRefCount() == 0) {
            stack.push(&node);
        }
    }
    
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        auto& node = *stack.back();
        stack.pop();
        …
        std::invoke(std::forward<Executor>(executor), node);
        …
    }
}
```

The above function takes a reference to the lists of nodes and edges, so that these can stay `private` inside `Graph`. And `Graph::Execute()` just becomes:

```
void Graph::Execute()
{
    for (auto& pin : pins) {
        pin.Reset();
    }

    for (auto Edge& edge : edges) {
         pins[edge->fromPin].IncrementRefCount();
    }

    execute_dag(nodes, edges, [](Node& node){ node.Execute(); });
}
```

The above assumes that `Node` still has a `refCount` and `isTarget()`. Since `refCount` is only needed during the DAG traversal, you could instead create a temporary vector holding the reference counts inside `execute_dag()`. For `isTarget()`, you could consider having the executor return a `bool` to indicate whether to process the incoming edges or not, so the executor can return `false` if `node.isTarget() == false`. This decouples knowledge of `isTarget()` from the DAG algorithm. Finally, `getOutgoingEdges()` and `getIncomingEdges()` are quite simple and can be inlined into `execute_dag()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me double-check your first statement because I believe it was my first idea and it didn't work as intended.

Comment: Alright, so I remembered why I used pointers and ArenaAllocate. See, nodes, pins and edges capacity is reserved in a Graph constructor, but what if somehow there'll be more than 16 nodes? In that case, the program won't work well, because at some point, let's say `auto& lit = sg.AddNode("lit")` will be pointing to an invalid memory address.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to address that. The solution is to use a `std::deque` or `std::list` instead of a `std::vector` then, as the former two have stable pointers.